# Add banner/notification to the selected email

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-api

The Outlook Insights Add-in adds banners (or notification) to emails when You select the email.
Banners looks like this:
[image]

Am I wondering how this was achieved and how the add-in activated to add the notification?

My main idea is to add notification to emails from Outside organization:

1. I want to activate add-in based on Envelope Sender or Message Header
2. Add-in should show notification notification (like from screenshot
   above) when mailbox.item is selected

But I could not figure out what objects in API could handle this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Launching the add-in automatically is an on going feature and not yet available in current outlook builds. For adding the notification we have infobar feature for add-ins. For more details please check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview).